# what's different between f:T=>:Double and f:T=>Double?

Tags: scala, types

I have see book title "Scala: Applied Machine Learning", for below part:

```
def statistics[T<:AnyVal](xt:XVSeries[T](implicit f:T=>:Double):Vector[Stats[T]]=xt.transpose.map(Stats[T](_))
def normalize[T<:AnyVal](xt:Xseries[T],low:Double,high:Double)(implicit ordering[T],f:T=>Double):Try[DBVector] ...
```

I don't understand what's differenet between `:` before `Double` and not of `f:T=>:Double` and `f:T=>Double`,

Comment: it could mean that there is a specific function type used in this book and implemented outside standard scala lib and imported into the code, but it seems that in this case it's just a typo in the book and will not compile.

Comment: note: if you have `trait =>:[A,B]` it's legal to use it like this `def test(f: String =>: Int) = ???`